# MVC SaveChanges not saving and no error returned

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have the following code which seems to be executing fine.  It throws no errors but nothing is actually saving in the db..

```
//write record to callque so we dont have to wait for IVRDM to hit
               tblCallQue tblcallque = new tblCallQue();
               tblcallque.ProjectCode = SessionVars.Session_ProjectCode;
               tblcallque.PhoneNumber = SessionVars.Session_PriPhone;
               tblcallque.IVRStartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
               tblcallque.IVRStopDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
               tblcallque.CallerID = "7208577900";
               tblcallque.RepositoryID = tblcallrepository.RepositoryID;
               tblcallque.AnswerTimeout = 30;
               tblcallque.Active = true;
               tblcallque.Mon_StartTime = "0800";
               tblcallque.Mon_StopTime = "2000";
               tblcallque.Tue_StartTime = "0800";
               tblcallque.Tue_StopTime = "2000";
               tblcallque.Wed_StartTime = "0800";
               tblcallque.Wed_StopTime = "2000";
               tblcallque.Thu_StartTime = "0800";
               tblcallque.Thu_StopTime = "2000";
               tblcallque.Fri_StartTime = "0800";
               tblcallque.Fri_StopTime = "2000";
               tblcallque.Sat_StartTime = "0800";
               tblcallque.Sat_StopTime = "2000";
               tblcallque.Sun_StartTime = "0800";
               tblcallque.Sun_StopTime = "2000";
               tblcallque.TextMessage = tblcalltype.TextMessage;
               tblcallque.ManuallyTriggerCall = true;
               tblcallque.Debug = true;
               dbMaster.tblCallQues.AddObject(tblcallque);
               dbMaster.SaveChanges();
```

Thank you!

When I look at what is in tblcallque through the immediate window I get this...which looks valid to me and like I said, no errors are thrown.

```
?tblcallque
{IVRDashboard.Models.tblCallQue}
    base {System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject}: {IVRDashboard.Models.tblCallQue}
    _Active: true
    _AnswerTimeout: 30
    _CallerID: "7208577900"
    _Debug: true
    _Fri_StartTime: "0800"
    _Fri_StopTime: "2000"
    _ID: 0
    _IVRStartDate: {11/25/2013 9:14:55 AM}
    _IVRStopDate: {11/27/2013 9:14:55 AM}
    _ManuallyTriggerCall: true
    _Mon_StartTime: "0800"
    _Mon_StopTime: "2000"
    _PhoneNumber: "3036141227"
    _ProjectCode: "DEM"
    _RepositoryID: 1167
    _Sat_StartTime: "0800"
    _Sat_StopTime: "2000"
    _Sun_StartTime: "0800"
    _Sun_StopTime: "2000"
    _TextMessage: false
    _Thu_StartTime: "0800"
    _Thu_StopTime: "2000"
    _Tue_StartTime: "0800"
    _Tue_StopTime: "2000"
    _Wed_StartTime: "0800"
    _Wed_StopTime: "2000"
    Active: true
    AnswerTimeout: 30
    CallerID: "7208577900"
    Debug: true
    Fri_StartTime: "0800"
    Fri_StopTime: "2000"
    ID: 0
    IVRStartDate: {11/25/2013 9:14:55 AM}
    IVRStopDate: {11/27/2013 9:14:55 AM}
    ManuallyTriggerCall: true
    Mon_StartTime: "0800"
    Mon_StopTime: "2000"
    PhoneNumber: "3036141227"
    ProjectCode: "DEM"
    RepositoryID: 1167
    Sat_StartTime: "0800"
    Sat_StopTime: "2000"
    Sun_StartTime: "0800"
    Sun_StopTime: "2000"
    TextMessage: false
    Thu_StartTime: "0800"
    Thu_StopTime: "2000"
    Tue_StartTime: "0800"
    Tue_StopTime: "2000"
    Wed_StartTime: "0800"
    Wed_StopTime: "2000"
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the `SaveChanges()` method isn't directly related to MVC. It's a part of EntityFramework.

Comment: Check your connectionstring

Comment: Do you maybe have a TransactionScope surrounding the query or the method? If the .Complete method of the TransactionScope object isn't called then it won't save.

Comment: kehrk - Yes, it is part of Entity Framework.  I should have said that.

Comment: Which version of EF are you using  ? And which approach did you use ?

Comment: There is no transaction Scope

Comment: EF version is v4.0.30319

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems I solved it - though I am not sure why this would work. If anyone knows, please feel free to reply.

Originally I had the following code...

```
if (tblcallrepository != null)
           {
               //write record to callque so we dont have to wait for IVRDM to hit
               IVRMaster_VoxeoEntities dbMaster = new IVRMaster_VoxeoEntities(SessionVars.Session_IVRMasterConnectString);
               tblCallQue tblcallque = new tblCallQue();
               tblcallque.ProjectCode = SessionVars.Session_ProjectCode;
               tblcallque.PhoneNumber = SessionVars.Session_PriPhone;
               tblcallque.IVRStartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
               tblcallque.IVRStopDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
               tblcallque.CallerID = "7208577900";
               tblcallque.RepositoryID = tblcallrepository.RepositoryID;
               tblcallque.AnswerTimeout = 30;
               tblcallque.Active = true; 
               tblcallque.Mon_StartTime = "0800";
               tblcallque.Mon_StopTime = "2000";
               tblcallque.Tue_StartTime = "0800";
               tblcallque.Tue_StopTime = "2000";
               tblcallque.Wed_StartTime = "0800";
               tblcallque.Wed_StopTime = "2000";
               tblcallque.Thu_StartTime = "0800";
               tblcallque.Thu_StopTime = "2000";
               tblcallque.Fri_StartTime = "0800";
               tblcallque.Fri_StopTime = "2000";
               tblcallque.Sat_StartTime = "0800";
               tblcallque.Sat_StopTime = "2000";
               tblcallque.Sun_StartTime = "0800";
               tblcallque.Sun_StopTime = "2000";
               tblcallque.TextMessage = tblcalltype.TextMessage;
               tblcallque.ManuallyTriggerCall = true;
               tblcallque.Debug = false; 
               dbMaster.tblCallQues.AddObject(tblcallque);
               dbMaster.SaveChanges();
           }
```

I changed it to this and now it works... (Just moved it outside of the first IF statement)

```
if (tblcallrepository != null)
           {
               bContinue = true;
               //lookup calltpeid
                tblcalltype = db.tblCallTypes.SingleOrDefault(t => t.CallTypeID == tblcallrepository.CallTypeID);
               sResult = "Call has been triggered";
           }


           if (bContinue)
           {
               //now we trigger it here
               //tblcallrepository.ManuallyTriggerCall = true;
               //db.tblCallRepositories.ApplyCurrentValues(tblcallrepository);
               //db.SaveChanges();

               //write record to callque so we dont have to wait for IVRDM to hit
               IVRMaster_VoxeoEntities dbMaster = new IVRMaster_VoxeoEntities(SessionVars.Session_IVRMasterConnectString);
               tblCallQue tblcallque = new tblCallQue();
               tblcallque.ProjectCode = SessionVars.Session_ProjectCode;
               tblcallque.PhoneNumber = SessionVars.Session_PriPhone;
               tblcallque.IVRStartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
               tblcallque.IVRStopDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
               tblcallque.CallerID = "7208577900";
               tblcallque.RepositoryID = tblcallrepository.RepositoryID;
               tblcallque.AnswerTimeout = 30;
               tblcallque.Active = true; 
               tblcallque.Mon_StartTime = "0800";
               tblcallque.Mon_StopTime = "2000";
               tblcallque.Tue_StartTime = "0800";
               tblcallque.Tue_StopTime = "2000";
               tblcallque.Wed_StartTime = "0800";
               tblcallque.Wed_StopTime = "2000";
               tblcallque.Thu_StartTime = "0800";
               tblcallque.Thu_StopTime = "2000";
               tblcallque.Fri_StartTime = "0800";
               tblcallque.Fri_StopTime = "2000";
               tblcallque.Sat_StartTime = "0800";
               tblcallque.Sat_StopTime = "2000";
               tblcallque.Sun_StartTime = "0800";
               tblcallque.Sun_StopTime = "2000";
               tblcallque.TextMessage = tblcalltype.TextMessage;
               tblcallque.ManuallyTriggerCall = true;
               tblcallque.Debug = false; 
               dbMaster.tblCallQues.AddObject(tblcallque);
               dbMaster.SaveChanges();
           }
```